# keyof operator in typescript includes undefined in type

Tags: typescript

According to the documentation for typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html
a type which is the keyof an object should be a union of all the keys in the object. Given that, I should expect the MetaObjectKey type to be "title" | "description" | "image" | "url" | "site_name" | "type"

This however does not seem to be the case as I cast the result of
const key = ogTags[i].split(':')[1] as MetaObjectKey;
as a MetaObject key yet still get the typescript error on the next line stating Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. when I try to assign to parsedMetaObject. What gives? This seems to be completely out of line with the documentation and potentially buggy.

Code sandbox link included as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-pt2t9z?file=/src/add.ts

```js
import { HTMLElement, parse } from 'node-html-parser';

interface MetaObject {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  url: string;
  site_name: string;
  type: string;
}

type MetaObjectKey = keyof MetaObject;

const ogTags = [
  'og:title',
  'og:description',
  'og:image',
  'og:url',
  'og:site_name',
  'og:type'
];

export const generateHTMLNodes: (data: string) => HTMLElement = (data) =>
  parse(data);

export const extractMetaTagsFromHTMLRoot: (
  rootElement: HTMLElement
) => MetaObject = (rootElement) => {
  const allMetaNodes = rootElement.querySelectorAll('meta');

  const parsedMetaObject: MetaObject = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    image: '',
    url: '',
    site_name: '',
    type: ''
  };

  allMetaNodes.forEach((aMN) => {
    const i = ogTags.findIndex((e) => e === aMN.getAttribute('name'));
    if (i >= 0) {
      const key = ogTags[i].split(':')[1] as MetaObjectKey;
      parsedMetaObject[key] = aMN.getAttribute('content');
    }
  });
  return parsedMetaObject;
};
export default generateHTMLNodes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all value of the `MetaObject` is string, it need to be asserted as might be aMN.getAttribute('content') would result in undefined or null.

What you need to add is to assert for string.

```
parsedMetaObject[key] = aMN.getAttribute('content') as string;
```

**OR** in the if condition add this condition too.

```
if (i >= 0 && aMN.getAttribute('content'))
```

Comment: I agree with your solution and after I figured out what I was doing wrong from my answer, post that's what I did. I ended up using the nullish coalescing operator ?? like my answer was, but I'll mark your answer as correct as it is equally correct and I appreciate the time you put into answering.

Comment: Use of ?? is also an alternate solution. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. The typescript compiler wasn't complaining about the key, it was complaining about the return value of getAttribute being string | undefined. I updated the following to ensure that string is assigned.

```js
allMetaNodes.forEach((aMN) => {
    const i = ogTags.findIndex((e) => e === aMN.getAttribute('name'));
    if (i >= 0) {
      const key = ogTags[i].split(':')[1] as MetaObjectKey;
      parsedMetaObject[key] = aMN.getAttribute('content') ?? '';
    }
  });
```